# Centering single item vertically inside Row

Tags: flutter

I am a total Flutter beginner and I have been banging my head against the wall to solve this problem for a little while now, how do I center a single item inside a Row vertically? (Not all of them, just a single one).

I have the following code and I am trying to center the icon at the end (arrow_right):

```
return Card(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: DDragon.getSpellImage(spell),
          placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(spell.name,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start),
                  spell is Passive
                      ? Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
                          child: Text("(Passive)",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)))
                      : SizedBox.shrink()
                ],
              ),
              Text(spell.description)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
    ],
  ),
);
```

I have tried the following with no success and change to the display whatsoever:

```
Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [Icon(Icons.arrow_right)])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Surround the icon in a `Center` widget. That should center it vertically, just the way you want it.

UPDATE:
I have made a dart pad to illustrate.
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c0bd50b6e61d303bb1d78e68c7412e3e

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, I tried that, it doesn't have any effect either

Comment: I have added a Dart Pad to my answer.

Comment: the problem or rather difference in your dart pad is that you have a height in your container and therefore Center will be able to center it. I figured out that I will need to center after the layouting is done, there is a good article here, so I'll try it with that https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407

Comment: I have removed the container with the set height and it still works the same

Comment: hmm yes, but now the container is taking the entire available space, instead of adjusting to it's contents size

Comment: For the dart pad, not you

Answer (score 0):

use expanded to make Row grow to full height and then use crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center

```
Expanded(child : Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Child Element",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me after a long while of Googling was wrapping my Row with IntrinsicHeight and wrapping the Icon inside Center, without that it would not center, no matter which answer I tried